# Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this code:

```
select inventory.store_id as store_id,
       film.title as Titel_Film, 
        count(film.film_id) as Anz_ausleihbar
from film
join inventory on film.film_id = inventory.film_id
join (select rental.inventory_id, rental.return_date 
      from rental 
      group by rental.inventory_id) as rental2
on rental2.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
where film.title like '%B'
and inventory.store_id = 1
group by film.film_id
order by inventory.store_id asc, film.title desc
```

I get the error Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: The parser chokes on the `as` before `rental2`. Due to unknow reasons Oracle doesn't allow it for table aliases, only for column aliases.

Comment: i deleted it and now I'm getting the Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: All Select columns without aggregate function must be in `GROUP BY`. Only MyQL allows strange things like your current query.

Comment: @dnoeth - why don't you put both comments as an answer, so we can upvote it, and OP can accept it as the definitive answer?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the inline view? `(select rental.inventory_id, rental.return_date 
      from rental 
      group by rental.inventory_id)`  I Don't see it being used anywhere.  Are you simply trying to only show films which have been rented?

Answer (score 0):

change your `GROUP BY` to

```
GROUP BY store_id, Titel_Film
```

When using group by, you need to specify "group fields" for all fields not being summarised or aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

- used a correlated subquery instead of an inline view to limit inventory based on the existence of a rental record.  Exists ***generally*** operates faster than `in` and if you need no data returned, faster than a join.  This also removed the `as` statement on the table alias.
- Eliminated Group by on inline view.
- Modified group by on outer query to include all non-aggregated fields from the select.
- shortened aliases

.

```
SELECT I.store_id as store_id
     , f.title as Titel_Film
     , count(f.film_id) as Anz_ausleihbar
FROM film
INNER JOIN inventory I
  ON f.film_id = I.film_id
WHERE f.title like '%B'
  AND i.store_id = 1
  AND exists (SELECT * 
              FROM rental r2 
              WHERE r2.inventory_ID = i.inventory_ID)
GROUP BY I.store_id 
       , film.title 
ORDER BY i.store_id asc, f.title desc
```